# fatal error: Array index out of range in swift 2 with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu-14.04

i have a problem with swift and i don't know how to solve it because I have just 2 months studying swift, and I am gradually learning, so here is the code:

```
import Foundation

var dir = "/home/guillermo/Escritorio/";
var file = "tokens";
var path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

guard var archivoTokens = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
    fatalError("failed to read archivoTokens from file")
}

var lineasArchivoTokens:[String] = archivoTokens.componentsSeparatedByString("\n");

var TOKENS:[String] = [String]();
var PATRONES:[String] = [String]();
var NOMBRES:[String] = [String]();

var count = lineasArchivoTokens.count;
for index in 0..<count{
    var tmpList:[String] = (lineasArchivoTokens[index]).componentsSeparatedByString(" ");
    PATRONES.append(tmpList[1]);
    NOMBRES.append(tmpList[0]);
}
```

and this is the error:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
Current stack trace:
/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so(swift_reportError+0x8b) [0x7fefd171dccb]
/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so(_swift_stdlib_reportFatalError+0x3d) [0x7fefd172e0cd]
/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so(+0x28d192) [0x7fefd1681192]
/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so(function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> ()+0x34) [0x7fefd1681294]
/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so(+0x16f0b5) [0x7fefd15630b5]
.build/debug/lexico7() [0x40165b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fefcf971ec5]
.build/debug/lexico7() [0x401049]
Instrucción ilegal (`core' generado)
```

Comment: Your code assume that `var tmpList = ...` has (at least) two elements. Perhaps  that is not the case for your input data? Have to tried to *debug* the problem?

Comment: yes, in this case I'm using ubuntu, i can only work in terminal, so use .build/ debug/ and display the above error

Comment: You can always add print() statements to show intermediate results...

Comment: I just saw that there is an overload of impressions (
i.e. print infinitely) in the tokens file , hence the error